# Add and remove class if input is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I've a problem with adding and removing a class when input is empty.

Code also available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50jztb94/11/).

```js
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var underlineFocus = document.getElementsByClassName("underline-focus");

function changeUnderline() {
  if (name === "") {
    underlineFocus[0].classList.add("underline-focus-empty");
  } else {
    underlineFocus[0].classList.remove("underline-focus-empty");
  }
  if (lastname === "") {
    underlineFocus[1].classList.add("underline-focus-empty");
  } else {
    underlineFocus[1].classList.remove("underline-focus-empty");
  }
}
changeUnderline();
```

```css
form {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.underline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  background-color: #1a2c5b;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}

.underline-focus {
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7971ea;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10;
}

input:focus+.underline-focus {
  width: 100%;
}

.underline-empty,
.underline-focus-empty {
  background-color: #f95959;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name *</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="changeUnderline();" required>
  <div class="underline-focus"></div>
  <div class="underline"></div>
  <label for="lastname">Last Name *</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" onchange="changeUnderline();" required>
  <div class="underline-focus"></div>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</form>
```

I've already looked at other questions and can't find the answer.

Comment: As the red box said, please add your code to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please post your code here. It's not right to reference an outside URL, as this may change making the whole question useless

Comment: I can't, because it's "too much code"

Comment: I can't for this alert: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: That's because a question should also tell us what you are trying to do, what research you have done, and the results or errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 major errors in your code.
1) by using `<form>`  each enter send your data to nowhere and refresh all input to null
2) you can't use the word "name" for a variable.

```js
var X_name = document.getElementById("name");
var underlineFocus = document.getElementsByClassName("underline-focus");

function changeUnderline() {

  if (X_name.value === "") {
    underlineFocus[0].classList.add("underline-focus-empty");
  } else {
    underlineFocus[0].classList.remove("underline-focus-empty");
  }
}
changeUnderline();
```

```css
form {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.underline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  background-color: #1a2c5b;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}

.underline-focus {
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7971ea;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10;
}

input:focus+.underline-focus {
  width: 100%;
}

.underline-empty,
.underline-focus-empty {
  background-color: #f95959;
}
```

```html
  <!--form -->
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="changeUnderline();" required>
    <div class="underline-focus"></div>
    <div class="underline"></div>
  <!--/form -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
PD. I didn't know about naming a variable "name"